# Why was the Elder Wand destroyed rather than returned to Dumbledore's tomb?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

Was there ever a reason given for Harry breaking The Elder Wand in two and throwing it away, before even repairing his own wand, contrary to the books, wherein he confers with the portrait of Dumbledore and they decide that after Harry mends his old wand using the Elder wand, he'll bury the Elder Wand in Dumbledore's tomb so that if Harry dies a natural death, the wand's ownership never passes on to anyone else.

Doesn't the end in the movie dispute this ? Additionally, if wands can simply be repaired (*'Reparo'*), couldn't the Elder Wand as well be repaired by someone who discovers its two pieces ?

Comment: Addressing the second point, only the Elder Wand is powerful enough to repair a broken wand.

Comment: Answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79998/20774) on SFF:SE. From a filmmaking perspective, it would have been too difficult to explain to audiences why he was leaving the wand in-situ. It would have required an extra scene and nearly a minute of needless dialogue.

Comment: Why would anyone think its good to leave one of the three most powerful magical artifacts in existence just lying around... Dumbledore is a dumbleidiot

Comment: @Richard : Is there a source which mentions that only the Elder Wand can mend other wands, since I don't seem to recall such a reference in any of the books to it ?

Comment: @stark - It's stated (by Ollivander) that [a broken wand can't be repaired](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118306/20774). The fact that we then see a wizard as *decidedly average* as Harry do the undoable is testament to the power of the Elder Wand

Comment: That leads to another question. Couldn't you "just" get another one? I mean, the Peverell Story seems to be true, except for the death. It's said, these 3 brothers were so powerful, they created the deathly hallows on their own. And Harry, Ron and Hermione are really powerful too. I know they wouldn't, but couldn't they create another wand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can clearly remember Harry saying after the battle, when he is alone with Hermoine and Ron, that the "wand is more trouble than it is worth".

The reason behind this is that in the wide world of countless wizards, there is bound to be one that may possibly defeat Harry and take the wand for his own (assuming he finds out where it is and the story behind it).

What are the chances that that particular wizard uses the Elder Wand for his own nefarious goals! Very high I would say!

So Harry chose not to tempt fate and destroy the wand seeing as he is not ambitious enough to want it for himself.

Problem solved...oh wait.. he avoided any problem in the first place!

Also, referring to your question summary and the following quote:

> Addressing the second point, only the Elder Wand is powerful enough to repair a broken wand. – user7812 Mar 25 at 17:06

I think the reverse of this is true. That the **Elder Wand is too powerful to be fixed by an ordinary wand**!!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to coder0007's answer, it could also be summed up thusly: **clearly the wand wasn't terribly secure in Dumbledore's grave.**

I mean all Voldemort seemingly had to do was lift the top of his sarcophagus and then remove it. We're talking about a guy who basically made sure people had to go through hell to find his horcruxes, and then all he has to do is use magic to lift the lid of a tomb and take it?

But then again, Dumbledore likely intended this by design as he was a very clever man in addition to being one of the most powerful wizards ever. He even knew his role in the grand scheme of things was to die, and to think that Draco could disarm Dumbledore with ease is a bit of a stretch as well, as remember: that's what caused the wand's allegiance to switch, meaning neither Voldemort nor Snape were the people the wand would answer to.

Dumbledore basically knew how things had to go down, and allowed things to progress as they should.